# PHP Simple HTML DOM Getting ONLY first 5 links inside a div class

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

So far I have this

```
<?PHP include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mangastream.com/');
foreach($html->find('.side-nav') as $t)
foreach($t->find('a')as $k)
echo $k->href . '<br>'; 
?>
```

which outputs all the links from inside the class. but I just want to have the first 5 links.

Comment: You write about HTML but infact this is an array. So why not learn about arrays first? http://php.net/array http://php.net/book.array - In any case there is [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/ArrayIterator) and [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) as well.

Comment: i looked at it. and i know im supposed to use an array. im just unsure how to get a link to store as an array because it seems like the entire output of links are not separate to be stored separately atm.

Comment: simple html dom returns you an array - I showed an example in an answer I added below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try that

```
<?PHP include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mangastream.com/');
foreach($html->find('.side-nav') as $t){
    foreach($t->find('a')as $key => $k){
        echo $k->href . '<br>';
        if($key >= 4){
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ty very much. how do i add to ur reputation?

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns an array, you can do a single find operation instead of two, and you can slice an array to the first five elements by using `array_slice`.

This allows you to get the first five element easily:

```
$ks = $html->find('.side-nav a');
foreach (array_slice($ks, 0, 5) as $k)
    echo $k->href, '<br>'
;
```

However I suggest you take the DOMDocument based HTML parser - perhaps in compbination with SimpleXML so that you can run xpath queries on the document instead.